# Entice and Persuade

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Could someone provide insight into the following

difference between entice and persuade

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary to see the differences in how the two words are defined?

Comment: @phenry I did, asking in a public forum would give different opinions and would have vividness effect.

Answer (score 4):

As per Merriam Webster Online:

**persuade**: to cause (someone) to do something by asking, arguing, or giving reasons

**entice**: to attract (someone) especially by offering or showing something that is appealing, interesting, etc.

I would persuade you using the impeccable logic of my arguments.

and

I would entice you with the offer of candy.